# .Net Core Web API with JWT authentication and multiple providers

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a .Net Core Web API app that implements JWT based authentication, and planning to offer to users different providers. They should be able to sign up using whatever Facebook, Google or Twitter account they have.

For MVC applications, there are libraries such [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers), that implements cookie based authentication, but I can't find anything similar for Web APIs. Although I have been searching all sort of online resources, I don't believe I'm the first trying to achieve this goal.

I don't mind doing it from scratch (actually I'm learning a lot), but I have a feeling I'm missing something.

Is there any library/nuget package that offers out-of-box JWT based authentication with multiple providers?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication lib contains all extensions you need.
You can enable them by chaining them on the AddAuthentication() method on the IServiceCollection.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { ...})
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {...})
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions => { ... })
        .AddGoogle(googleOptions => { ... })
        .AddTwitter(twitterOptions => { ... })
        .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => { ... });

}
```

Read the section below [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#configure-facebook-authentication) code for a nice explaination.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I could use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` with the `AddJwtBearer`. However, it doesn't really help much, I think. I was looking for some component that could wrap the communication with the external providers, so I wouldn't need to keep the URLs for authentication and do the HttpClient requests myself.

Comment: @luizs81 ok, i see. I thought you would like to do it from "scratch", then this is the way. Please upvote if answer was to any help :)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't help much and I'm not sure how Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication interacts with JWT in controller level. I can't find any documentation. All the Microsoft examples use MVC and scaffold pages.